# How to group in data.table with overlapping value?

Tags: r, data.table

i have a question relating to data.table in R.
I am working on an acceleration data that requires me to generate features from the raw data. I want to group data by each 2 second. It is easy by generating 1 more column to indicate groups for each 2 second and group with by.
However, i want do the overlapping windows. For example, my raw data is this

```
a=data.table(x = c(1:10), y= c(2:11), z = c(5), second=rep(c(1:5),each=2))
```

> x  y z     second
>
> 1:  1  2 5      1
>
> 2:  2  3 5      1
>
> 3:  3  4 5      2
>
> 4:  4  5 5      2
>
> 5:  5  6 5      3
>
> 6:  6  7 5      3
>
> 7:  7  8 5      4
>
> 8:  8  9 5      4
>
> 9:  9 10 5      5
>
> 10: 10 11 5      5

Now, i want to calculate the mean of x,y,z column by each 2 seconds. 1and2, 2 and 3, 3 and 4, 4 and 5.
I can run the for loops but since i have a huge dataset, it will take a long time. Do you know how do to it with just data table tools?
Thanks so much

Comment: Please show your desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there is only 2 unique observations for 'second', we get the `lead` of the 'x', 'y', 'z' columns, grouped by 'second', `unlist` the Subset of Data.table and get the `mean`.

```
nm1 <- c("x", "y", "z")
na.omit(a[, paste0(nm1, 2)  := lapply(.SD, function(x) shift(x, 2, 
     type = "lead")), .SDcols = nm1])[, .(Mean = mean(unlist(.SD))),
           .(second = paste0(second, "-", second + 1))]
#  second     Mean
#1:    1-2 3.666667
#2:    2-3 5.000000
#3:    3-4 6.333333
#4:    4-5 7.666667
```

---

Or a slightly more compact option would be

```
library(dplyr)
cbind(a[second!= last(second)], a[second!= first(second)])[
    ,.(Mean = mean(unlist(.SD))), .(second = paste0(second, "-", second+1))]
#   second     Mean
#1:    1-2 3.666667
#2:    2-3 5.000000
#3:    3-4 6.333333
#4:    4-5 7.666667
```

---

Or another option would be place them in a `list`, `rbind` the dataset, create a new 'id1' column, get the `mean` after `unlist`ing the `.SDcols` or we can get the individual `mean` of each column

```
dt1 <- rbindlist(list(a[second!= last(second)], 
     a[second!= first(second)]), idcol=TRUE)[, id1:= as.numeric(gl(.N, 2, .N)), .id][]
```

Get the `mean` for each column by 'second'

```
dt1[, lapply(.SD, mean), .(second = paste0(id1, "-", id1 + 1)), .SDcols = x:z]
```

Get the whole `mean` by 'second'

```
dt1[, mean(unlist(.SD)), .(second = paste0(id1, "-", id1 +1)), .SDcols = x:z]
```

Comment: Im sorry, what is the object nm1 here?

Comment: @ThanhQuang It is the 'x', 'y', 'z'. Updated

Comment: Hi, Akrun, what if i want to calculate the individual mean value of x ,y z for each 2 second?

Comment: @ThanhQuang Instead of `unlist`, we do `lapply(.SD, mean)`

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way:

```
ag = data.table(
  second = c(1:2, 2:3, 3:4, 4:5), 
  g = rep(paste(1:4, 2:5, sep="-"), each=2)
)

a[ag, on="second"][, mean(unlist(.SD)), by=g, .SDcols=x:z]

#      g       V1
# 1: 1-2 3.666667
# 2: 2-3 5.000000
# 3: 3-4 6.333333
# 4: 4-5 7.666667
```

I'm sure you could write `ag` less manually, but it's not clear to me what the rules behind it are.

Generally, if you are computing statistics *across columns*, then your data is not well-formatted. If you have time, I'd suggest reading about [making data "tidy"](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v059i10).